# How to assign a Dictionary to AnyObject in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, casting

I have been playing around with Swift. I have had multiple errors with types, especially working with Swift and my old Objective-C classes. The problem with this method is: I am expecting an array made of NSDictionarys in Objective-C.

```
var curArr:[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = self.getItemsForCurrentStack()
var arrToReturn:[(Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>)] = []
for obj in curArr{
    arrToReturn.append(["image": UIImage(named: obj["imageName"] as! String), "color": UIColor(red:obj["colorDic"]!["red"] as! CGFloat, green:obj["colorDic"]!["green"] as! CGFloat, blue:obj["colorDic"]!["blue"] as! CGFloat, alpha:1.0), "percentage": obj["percantage"]])
}
return arrToReturn
```

This returns Dictionaries (which are NSDictionaries) in Swift. But the last line throws me an error:

> Dictionary' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

I've tried using `as! [AnyObject]`

But that throws another error:

> 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'Dictionary'

I don't get the second error, since this doesn't have to be a subtype, but the other way around. Any ideas on how to solve this? I didn't find an answer for several hours of googleing and researching.

Comment: var arrToReturn:[String:AnyObject] = [] or var arrToReturn:[AnyObject] = [] if you want to return an array of AnyObjects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Dictionary` is a struct in Swift, whereas `AnyObject` is

> /// The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.

Depending what you're trying to do, you may want to use `Any` in your code, or cast your dictionary to NSDictionary using `as NSDictionary`.

---

**Edit after your clarification:**

If you split up the `append` call from the dictionary itself, you see a better error message:

[image]

So, the issue is that your dictionary contains some `Optional` values, but Optional is a struct and not convertible to Obj-C. You can fix by casting to `UIImage!` and `AnyObject!` (ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional), or by using `as!`.

Comment: If I do this by `var arrToReturn:[NSDictionary] = []
        for obj in curArr{
            arrToReturn.append(["image": UIImage(named: obj["imageName"] as! String), "color": UIColor(red:obj["colorDic"]!["red"] as! CGFloat, green:obj["colorDic"]!["green"] as! CGFloat, blue:obj["colorDic"]!["blue"] as! CGFloat, alpha:1.0), "percentage": obj["percantage"]] as! NSDictionary)
        }`,
 I get the error: `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(NSDictionary)'`

Comment: Using Any is not possible because this method is generated by Xcode and  cannot be changed because it expects an NSArray in Objective-C code.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? It works for me.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.3, so the latest official version. The whole playground I am testing this in: http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150419/gcgqk9t9.png

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in playground, without compile or runtime errors. Here is what I added to populate `curArr`:

```
var curArr:[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = [
    [
        "imageName" : "photo.jpg",
        "colorDic" : ["red" : 1.0, "green" : 0.0, "blue" : 0.0],
        "percentage" : 0.5
    ]
]
```

With all this forced unwrapping I think you just have to make sure that what `self.getItemsForCurrentStack()` returns is indeed what you expect.

Result in playground:

```
[
 "percentage": {Some 5.0e+-1}, 
 "image": nil, 
 "color": {Some r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 1,0}
]
```

My recommendation would be to refactor into objects - that would make your code so much more readable!

Comment: The problem is not that code, but the return statement, returning arrToReturn where an Array of NSDictionaries or other objects is expected.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**

```
code:

var curArr:[Dictionary<String, Any>] = [
[
        "imageName" : "photo.jpg",
        "colorDic" :[
            "red" : 1.0,
            "green" : 0.0,
            "blue" : 0.0
        ],
        "percentage" : 0.5
    ]
]
```

[image]